# How to parse response from google maps API with JSON?

Tags: c#, json, google-maps

I want to calculate the distance between points in C# with the google maps distance matrix API.

I use the following code to make the request :

```
private void MapsAPICall()
    {
        //Pass request to google api with orgin and destination details
        HttpWebRequest request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
            + "51.123959,3.326682" + "&destinations=" + "51.158089,4.145267" 
            + "&mode=Car&language=us-en&sensor=false");

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                Distance t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Distance>(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I want to parse the json answer into the Distance class:

```
public struct Distance
{
   // Here I want to parse the distance and duration
}
```

Here is an example of the json response I receive : 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

How do I parse the distance and duration into the Distance class?
This is the first time I use Json so I'm not experienced with it.

Ps: I have the json.net library installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) has an option to 'Paste JSON as classes'. This will generate the classes you need to deserialize your JSON.

Using this option will generate the following for you:

```
public class Distance
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Duration
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public Distance distance { get; set; }
    public Duration duration { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public Element[] elements { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public string[] destination_addresses { get; set; }
    public string[] origin_addresses { get; set; }
    public Row[] rows { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

*(If you want, you can refactor the generated code to make it more readable. You will need to add Json.NET attributes to make sure that serialization is still working)*

Then inside your code you can use the following line to deserialize your code:

```
Parent result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update for Visual Studio 2015+**

As a complement to Wouter de Kort's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703738/3180489), here is an update for Visual Studio 2015+.

Visual Studio 2015+ has that handy '*Paste JSON as Classes*' that Wouter kindly  described.

To generate the needed classes for GoogleMaps API JSON deserialization *yourself*:

1. In a Web Browser or REST client, navigate to the GoogleMaps API URL with some test parameters populated. For example: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=30.3449153,-81.860543&destinations=33.7676932,-84.4906437&language=en-US&units=imperial&key=<API_KEY>`
2. Copy (`Ctrl+C`) the resulting raw JSON response from your browser/client to your clipboard.
3. In Visual Studio 2015+, open the `.cs` file in which you would like to create the classes.
4. Place your cursor in the `.cs` file where you would like the classes generated.
5. From Visual Studio's menu choose *Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes*

**Example of Resulting Classes**

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string[] destination_addresses { get; set; }
    public string[] origin_addresses { get; set; }
    public Row[] rows { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public Element[] elements { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public Distance distance { get; set; }
    public Duration duration { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Distance
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class Duration
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

From that point on, you can follow the rest of Wouter's advice.

```
Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's late but could be useful to someone. In such cases where we have a JSON string and wants to have a proper class structure to deserialize it correctly, you may use online tool http://json2csharp.com/

Just paste your JSON string and click on *Generate* button. It will provide you with the required class structure. It's that simple. This approach is useful when you want to avoid installing external tools.

Answer (score -1):

The 'Distance' type will need to correctly model the JSON schema e.g:

```
public string[] destination_addresses { get; set; }
public string[] origin_addresses { get; set; }
public Row[] rows { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
```

(and of course then the sub-types like `Row` will also need to be modelled)

Other than that, your usage of Json.Net:

```
Distance t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Distance>(result);
```

should be ok

Comment: Sorry, I was mid-edit - hopefully the latest edits go some way to more fully answering the question